# How to debug SSIS Package - SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

How to debug SSIS Package - SQL 2008? I am calling the package from C# Code. But the package is not executing. I want to debug the SSIS Package and trace the paramter values.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you [debug packages in BIDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137880.aspx), although you can directly [attach a debugger to the host processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403356.aspx) too, if you're doing something special. Does this not do what you need?

Alternatively, use 'manual debugging', i.e. message boxes, writing the parameter values to a log file, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Did you know that you can start package execution from the command line:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /File <your package name>
```

So for debugging, go to your project's Properties | Debug. Set the 'Start Action' to **c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe**. Set the 'Command line arguments' to **/File (your package name)**.

Set some breakpoints in your code, and F5 to run your project. If all goes well, it should stop when it encounters your breakpoint.

I do this often, it works quite well.

Comment: Set some breakpoint - Inside the Package like DataFlow / Task Modules..??  and then call from Command prompt ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I thought you were having problems in your C# code. You still may be able to set breakpoints in your C# code and then use the debugger to view variables, etc. Variables can be gotten at from certain SSIS C# classes, you may be using one of them.